# Android: Manipulating Parsed JSON for an IF Statement

Tags: android, database, json

I am developing an android application that uses sql & php to connect to an external server. I AM able to retrieve the correct information into the application, however, I am having trouble manipulating the parsed JSON data

This code successfully returns the data that I queried.

```
try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag","venID: "+json_data.getInt("venID")
                        );
                        //Get an output to the screen
                        returnString += jArray.getJSONObject(i); 


                }
        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        return returnString; 
    }
```

I verify that the data that I want returned is correct by putting it into a textview:

```
final TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121));
```

and it displays the results as:

```
http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/sponsorimage.php{"venID":"1"}
```

I am wondering how I may manipulate the returned information to either have the result just display the number 1 as I am trying to take that string and use it in an if statement to perform another action

**EDIT**

Here is the full code for this particular section

```
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/sponsorimage.php"; //i use my real ip here



private String getServerData(String returnString) {

   InputStream is = null;

   String result = "";
    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sponsorImage","0"));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","venID: "+json_data.getInt("venID")
                    );
                    //Get an output to the screen
                    returnString += jArray.getJSONObject(i); 


            }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return returnString; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to access the venID parameter of your JSON object (in this case "1"), you could use the JSONObject.getInt(String key) method. You're already using it inside your log statement.

```
JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
Log.i("log_tag","venID: "+json_data.getInt("venID")
```

This way you can access any parameter of a JSON object
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

-axel

Comment: Okay. I changed  the returnstring to -->

returnString += json_data.getInt("venID");

and it now returns:  xxx.xxx.x.xxx/sponsorimage.php1

How do I get the xxx.xxx.x.xxx/sponsorimage.php to not be included?

Comment: you pass the returnString as parameter to this function and then append every JSON object of your JSON array... so just use a new string for your result

Answer (score 0):

Well,  you just walked through JSON array and concatendated all the objects to single string. And you got this string back.   Why you are doing this if you need only one field of one object?

PS:   is is better to use StringBuilder instead += on strings.

Comment: I am following an example I was given. Eventually, I will need to concatenate many things to a single string.

My questions is, how do I manipulate the returned information http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/sponsorimage.php{"venID":"1"} to display just the 1?

Comment: You could use  split("\"")[3] to get to this numbe, but it os fragile and ugly hack.  Better solution owuld be to implement proper parsing of JSON object, or just extract  proper value instead of concatenating everything and kitchen sink.

Comment: I have tried the "\" split and that was unsuccessful. What would you suggest as proper parsing of the JSON object. Any hints or areas that I could look at? would that be done in the php script or the android file?

Comment: See the next answer.   I would recomment  reading some decent java book first.